# Best practice for storing application const strings in the code

Tags: c#, string, constants

In my application (C#) i have lots of const messages which are get printed to the log, presented to the user, etc. 
This const messages are not suppose to change so there is no point putting them in an external file or DB.
My solution is very simple - I am thinking about creating a static class and naming it ConstMessages. This class will simply hold lots of public const string variables which can be accessed from anywhere in the application.
Can you please suggest if there anything wrong with that method and if there are better ways?
Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for a non-recommended solution; you must use external file (like configuration file `.app` or `.config`) to store these messages.

Comment: Why put them in one class if these strings won't change?  It seems that you are expecting some change for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use readonly instead of const to get over versioning issues.

Comment: Versioning-issues using const? How so?

Comment: Const are compile time whereas readonly is runtime. More info here http://www.shrinkrays.net/code-snippets/csharp/const-vs-readonly-in-csharp.aspx

Comment: @Alxandr: If you use constants in an assembly that is reused in multiple places within the code, you would be forced to recompile all the client code that uses the assembly because the value would be hard-coded by the compiler. With a read-only value, the value is resolved at run-time. So just plugging in a new version of the assembly would cause the client code to use the new value. There is a good chapter on this in this book: http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Covers-4-0-Specific-Development/dp/0321658701/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309707290&sr=8-1 (chapter 1: Item 2: Prefer readonly to const)

Comment: anivas's link is now at http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/const-vs-readonly-in-csharp/

Answer (score 5):

That's usually OK for simple applications - another option is a RESX file if you think there is a possibility the application will ever need to be localized / support more than one language.

Answer (score 2):

I would typically store these as application [Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28VS.80%29.aspx).